# Create Flow with Metadata API - Process Builder flow from Apex

Tags: metadata-api, process-builder, flow

I'm trying to create a Flow from apex using the MetadataService.Flow, in this case what I want to do is:

- Create the flow
- Define some criteria
- Invoke an apex class (defined with the @InvocableMethod)

So far I've defined this code:

```
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    service.SessionHeader                = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    service.SessionHeader.sessionId      = UserInfo.getSessionId();

    // Create Flow
    MetadataService.Flow flow = new MetadataService.Flow();
    flow.fullName             = 'FlowFromApex';
    flow.description          = 'Automatic creation';
    flow.label                = 'New Flow';
    flow.processType          = 'Flow';

    MetadataService.FlowApexPluginCall apex_pluggin = new MetadataService.FlowApexPluginCall();
    apex_pluggin.apexClass = 'mssgdirect_evaluateCondiitonHandler';

    List<MetadataService.FlowActionCall> actionCallsArray = new List<MetadataService.FlowActionCall>();
    MetadataService.FlowActionCall actioncall = new  MetadataService.FlowActionCall();
    actioncall.actionName = 'mssgdirect_invoke_apex';
    actioncall.actionType = 'chatterPost';
    actioncall.locationX  = 100;
    actioncall.locationY = 100;
    actionCallsArray.add(actioncall);


    flow.actionCalls = actionCallsArray;
    handleSaveResults(service.createMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { flow })[0]);
```

I'm using this code inside a Remote action method so when I execute this, I'm getting this error:

[image]

Am I missing something here, what is the best practice defining the tree for the flow (Example: Flow > FlowActionCall > FlowApexPluginCall > condition etc, etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I spent almost last night trying to figure it out, and I could create my process with this code, hope it helps:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    service.SessionHeader                = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    service.SessionHeader.sessionId      = UserInfo.getSessionId();



    MetadataService.FlowActionCallInputParameter inputparam1 = new MetadataService.FlowActionCallInputParameter();

    List<MetadataService.FlowActionCall> actionCallsArray = new List<MetadataService.FlowActionCall>();
    MetadataService.FlowActionCall actioncall             = new  MetadataService.FlowActionCall();        
    actioncall.name                                       = 'myRule_1_A1';
    actioncall.label                                      = 'invoca clase de apex';
    actioncall.locationX                                  = 100;
    actioncall.locationY                                  = 200;
    actioncall.actionName                                 = 'mssgdirect_evaluateCondiitonHandler';
    actioncall.actionType                                 = 'apex';
    actionCallsArray.add(actioncall);

    /**
     * ::::: CONDITIONS ::::::
     */
    MetadataService.FlowElementReferenceOrValue elementValue1= new Metadataservice.FlowElementReferenceOrValue();
    elementValue1.stringValue = 'String';

    List<Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue> list_metadataValue = new List<Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue>();
    Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue metadatavalue            = new MetadataService.FlowMetadataValue();
    metadatavalue.name                                         = 'operatorDataType';
    metadatavalue.value                                        = elementValue1;
    list_metadataValue.add(metadatavalue);

    Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue metadatavalue2           = new MetadataService.FlowMetadataValue();
    metadatavalue2.name                                        = 'inputDataType';
    metadatavalue2.value                                       = elementValue1;
    list_metadataValue.add(metadatavalue2);

    Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue metadatavalue3           = new MetadataService.FlowMetadataValue();
    metadatavalue3.name                                        = 'leftHandSideType';
    metadatavalue3.value                                       = elementValue1;
    list_metadataValue.add(metadatavalue3);

    Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue metadatavalue4           = new MetadataService.FlowMetadataValue();
    metadatavalue4.name                                        = 'rightHandSideType';
    metadatavalue4.value                                       = elementValue1;
    list_metadataValue.add(metadatavalue4);        

    MetadataService.FlowElementReferenceOrValue valueCriteria= new Metadataservice.FlowElementReferenceOrValue();
    valueCriteria.stringValue = 'YUCEL1';

    List<MetadataService.FlowCondition> listConditions = new List<MetadataService.FlowCondition>();
    MetadataService.FlowCondition condition            = new MetadataService.FlowCondition();
    condition.processMetadataValues                    = list_metadataValue;
    condition.operator                                 = 'EqualTo';
    condition.rightValue                               = valueCriteria;
    condition.leftValueReference                       = 'myVariable_current.Name';    
    listConditions.add(condition);


    /**
     * ::::: RULES ::::::
     */
    Metadataservice.FlowConnector flowConnectorinRule = new Metadataservice.FlowConnector();
    flowConnectorinRule.targetReference               = 'myRule_1_A1';

    List<MetadataService.FlowRule> list_rules = new List<MetadataService.FlowRule>();
    MetadataService.FlowRule rule             = new Metadataservice.FlowRule();
    rule.name                                 = 'myRule_1';
    rule.conditionLogic                       = 'and';
    rule.conditions                           = listConditions;
    rule.connector                            = flowConnectorinRule;
    rule.label                                = 'Valida criterios';
    list_rules.add(rule);


     /*
        ::::: decitions :::::
     */

    List<Metadataservice.FlowDecision> list_desicions = new List<Metadataservice.FlowDecision>();
    Metadataservice.FlowDecision flowDecision         = new Metadataservice.FlowDecision();
    flowDecision.name                                 = 'myDecision';
    flowDecision.label                                = 'Primary Decision';
    flowDecision.locationX                            = 50;
    flowDecision.locationY                            = 0;
    flowDecision.defaultConnectorLabel                = 'default';
    flowDecision.rules                                = list_rules;

    list_desicions.add(flowDecision);


     /*
        ::::: ASSIGMENTs :::::
     */
    Metadataservice.FlowConnector flowConnector          = new Metadataservice.FlowConnector();
    flowConnector.targetReference                        = 'myDecision';

    List<MetadataService.FlowAssignment> list_assigments = new List<MetadataService.FlowAssignment>();
    MetadataService.FlowAssignment assigment             = new MetadataService.FlowAssignment();
    assigment.name                                       = 'myVariable_waitStartTimeAssignment';
    assigment.label                                      = 'myVariable_waitStartTimeAssignment';
    assigment.locationX                                  = 0;
    assigment.locationY                                  = 0;
    assigment.connector                                  = flowConnector;

    List<MetadataService.FlowAssignmentItem> listAssigmentItem = new List<MetadataService.FlowAssignmentItem>();
    MetadataService.FlowAssignmentItem assigmentItem           = new MetadataService.FlowAssignmentItem();

    MetadataService.FlowElementReferenceOrValue elementValue   = new Metadataservice.FlowElementReferenceOrValue();
    elementValue.dateTimeValue                                 = Datetime.now();

    assigmentItem.assignToReference                            = 'myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable';
    assigmentItem.operator                                     = 'Assign';
    assigmentItem.value                                        = elementValue;
    listAssigmentItem.add(assigmentItem);

    assigment.assignmentItems                                  = listAssigmentItem;
    list_assigments.add(assigment);

     /*
        ::::: METADATA VALKUES :::::
     */
    List<Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue> flow_processMetadataValuesList = new List<Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue>();        
    MetadataService.FlowElementReferenceOrValue processMetatdataElement1 = new Metadataservice.FlowElementReferenceOrValue();
    Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue meta1                              = new Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue();
    processMetatdataElement1.stringValue                                 = 'Account';        
    meta1.name                                                           = 'ObjectType';
    meta1.value                                                          = processMetatdataElement1;
    flow_processMetadataValuesList.add(meta1);

    MetadataService.FlowElementReferenceOrValue processMetatdataElement2 = new Metadataservice.FlowElementReferenceOrValue();
    Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue meta2                              = new Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue();
    processMetatdataElement2.elementReference                            = 'myVariable_current';        
    meta2.name                                                           = 'ObjectVariable';
    meta2.value                                                          = processMetatdataElement2;
    flow_processMetadataValuesList.add(meta2);

    MetadataService.FlowElementReferenceOrValue processMetatdataElement3 = new Metadataservice.FlowElementReferenceOrValue();
    Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue meta3                              = new Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue();
    processMetatdataElement3.elementReference                            = 'myVariable_old';        
    meta3.name                                                           = 'OldObjectVariable';
    meta3.value                                                          = processMetatdataElement3;
    flow_processMetadataValuesList.add(meta3);

    MetadataService.FlowElementReferenceOrValue processMetatdataElement4 = new Metadataservice.FlowElementReferenceOrValue();
    Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue meta4                              = new Metadataservice.FlowMetadataValue();
    processMetatdataElement4.stringValue                                 = 'onCreateOnly';        
    meta4.name                                                           = 'TriggerType';
    meta4.value                                                          = processMetatdataElement4;
    flow_processMetadataValuesList.add(meta4);

    /*
        ::::: VARIABLES :::::
     */
    List<MetadataService.FlowVariable> list_variables = new List<MetadataService.FlowVariable>();        
    MetadataService.FlowVariable variable = new  MetadataService.FlowVariable();
    variable.name                         = 'myVariable_current';
    variable.dataType                     = 'SObject';
    variable.isCollection                 = false;
    variable.isInput                      = true;
    variable.isOutput                     = true;
    variable.objectType                   = 'Account';
    list_variables.add(variable);

    MetadataService.FlowVariable variable2 = new  MetadataService.FlowVariable();
    variable2.name                         = 'myVariable_old';
    variable2.dataType                     = 'SObject';
    variable2.isCollection                 = false;
    variable2.isInput                      = true;
    variable2.isOutput                     = true;
    variable2.objectType                   = 'Account';
    list_variables.add(variable2);

    MetadataService.FlowElementReferenceOrValue datetime_elementReference = new Metadataservice.FlowElementReferenceOrValue();
    datetime_elementReference.dateTimeValue = Datetime.now();

    MetadataService.FlowVariable variable3  = new  MetadataService.FlowVariable();
    variable3.name                          = 'myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable';
    variable3.dataType                      = 'DateTime';
    variable3.isCollection                  = false;
    variable3.isInput                       = false;
    variable3.isOutput                      = false;
    variable3.value                         = datetime_elementReference;
    list_variables.add(variable3);  

    /*
        ::::: FLOW :::::
     */
    MetadataService.Flow flow  = new MetadataService.Flow();
    flow.description           = 'Flujo sobre NombreDelObjeto';
    flow.interviewLabel        = 'Objecto_flujo-1_Account';
    flow.fullName              = 'myFlow-1';
    flow.label                 = 'Objecto flujo';
    flow.processType           = 'Workflow';
    flow.processMetadataValues = flow_processMetadataValuesList;
    flow.variables = list_variables;
    flow.assignments = list_assigments;
    flow.startElementReference = 'myVariable_waitStartTimeAssignment';
    flow.actionCalls = actionCallsArray;
    flow.decisions             = list_desicions;



    handleSaveResults(service.createMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { flow })[0]);
```

This is the result:

[image]